# ¿Cómo utilizar valores aleatorios?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, me gustaria saber qué hacer en el bucle for para no repetir el valor de la variable `punto`. Es decir, que no salga 2 veces el mismo valor. Tendría que utilizar el bucle IF pero no se como expresarlo

```
lista = range(len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir)
shuffle(lista)
for i in lista:
    punto = lista[i] #Se elige un punto para hacer el intercambio
    padre = random.sample(selected, indAReproducir) #Se eligen dos padres
```

ERROR DADO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, copia y pega el error en lugar de adjuntar una captura de pantalla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creas tu rango y generas una lista aleatoria con shuffle, y recorres esa lista que ya tiene los valores aleatorios.

```
lista = list(range(len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir)):
shuffle(lista)


for i in lista:
    punto =lista[i] 
...
```

Comment: Es correcto pero creo que no es lo que busco exactamente. Quiero un bucle IF de manera que si el valor de `punto`ya ha salido, haga de nuevo el random.randinit

Comment: qué es *bucle IF*? Tienes que pensar que `random.randint` tiene un número finito de resultados. Si no quieres que se repitan valores, entonces la solución de @joreldraw es la mejor. Crea un conjunto de valores posibles y ordénalos de forma aleatoria.

Comment: Pues un bucle IF/ELSE

Comment: @ChemaCortes  ´'range' object does not support item assignment"´. Este error da. Editado arriba el cambio y el error.

Comment: podrias hacer un bucle y añadir a una lista los resultados que ya salieron y comprobar que el nuevo random no exista ya en esa lista, pero eso puede ser explosivo. Desconozco la longitud del rango, pero si hablamos de rangos largos, puede ser que cuando la lista este bien completa, la probabilidad del random nuevo se va reduciendo drásticamente y llegara un momento que casi sea un loop infinito.

Comment: @joreldraw Algo asi es la idea, pero no se aplicarla. Comprobar que el random.init que salga no haya salido antes, y si ha salido ejecutar de nuevo la sentencia `punto`. Por eso decia un IF/ELSE pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: he actualizado el código para que te cree la lista ya que range no la devuelve.En cuanto a la solución lo que te comentaba antes es que la solución no es buena como tu dices. Puede demorarse mucho el encontrar un nuevo random cuando tengamos unos ranges altos.